# Funny scope issue in Javascript with global variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, global-variables

I have a big JS app with many modules, which will ultimately be bundled with `browersify.` But since I don't want to make my whole team install Node.js and rebuild every time they change a character, I want the modules to register globally just while developing. I've been using the standard registration for modules like so:

```
// if browserify
if (typeof module === "object" && module.exports) {
    module.exports = myModule;
} else { window.myModule = myModule; }
```

Here's where it gets funky: When requiring dependencies in the main app.js file, I do this:

```
if (typeof module === "object" && module.exports) {
    var myModule = require("./js/myModule");
} // otherwise it's assumed to be globe, which console.log(window) confirms
console.log(myModule);
```

This console log comes back as undefined, so I need an else line that says:
    } else {
       myModule = window.myModule;
    }

Here's a simpler [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ca4tezm/1/) as a proof of concept:

```
if (false) {
    var test = "Hello World";
} else {
  window.test = "Hello Globe";
}

document.getElementById("console").innerHTML = test;
```

`test` is undefined in this scenario.

What puzzles me is that the contents of the `if` statement that never runs seems to still register `test` as a local variable. Is that what's happening? Or do I just not understand how global variables work? I thought anything registered to `window` could be called by it's own name, just as we don't have to write `window.jQuery` every time.

Comment: Are you trying to assign variables to the window object in node? Because there's no window object in node.

Comment: The variable defined with var are global variables in node with in a file. But this scope issue is solved in latest Node. Node introduces
 let test = 'Hello';
Then test will not be accessible out side of if.

Comment: "*statement that never runs seems to still register test as a local variable*" - sure it does, that's how declarations work.

Comment: I think I understand. The variables are only globally assigned to window in the NON-Node environment. I was just surprised that they weren't globally available in that (development) environment. I was going by how Mike Bostock registers d3:

  if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) this.d3 = d3, define(d3); else if (typeof module === "object" && module.exports) module.exports = d3; else this.d3 = d3;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript hoists var declarations and since you are declaring inside the if statement that's not a new scope, basically having this:

```
if (false) {
    var test = "Hello World";
} else {
  window.test = "Hello Globe";
}
```

It's the same of having this:

```
var test;
if (false) {
  test = "Hello World";
} else {
  window.test = "Hello Globe";
}
```

That's why it's a good practice to declare your variables on the beginning of the scope, check this example:

```
var test = "Hello World From outside";
function(){
  console.log(test);
  if (false) {
    var test = "Hello World From inside"
  }
}
```

This example will output: **"undefined"** the var test is hoisted to the top of the scope, in this case the top of the function overwriting the outer variable declaration although we will never enter into that `if`

Comment: the "It's the same of having this" part is not quite correct. It should be
`var test; if(false) { test = "Hello World" }` Variable declarations are hoisted, not assignments.

Comment: Ah! Googling "hoisting" explains it -- And I thought I knew my JS. Thanks!